# How to resolve 415 unsupported media type error?

Tags: java, json, angular, rest, jax-rs

I have angular 5 which try to send PUT request to a rest service in java application:

**The Angular call:**

```
    ...
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    @Injectable()
    export class TripService {

...

    saveTrip(trip: Trip): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/Trip`, JSON.stringify(trip), httpOptions);
  }
```

**The server (java) service:**

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response updateTrip(Trip trip) {
    tripDao.updateTrip(trip);
    return Response.ok().entity("trip updated successfully").build();
}
```

**The entity!:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip")
@XmlRootElement
public class Trip implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @XmlElement(name = "user")
    private User user;
    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;
    ...
```

**Request header:**

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,he;q=0.8
Authorization: Bearer fake-jwt-token
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 538
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/manager/company
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
```

**The error:**

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/... /rest/Trip
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 415 Unsupported Media Type
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

I need help with the JSON to Java conversion ?  I have this jar for example:
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1

I added the jackson jars which included currently in the project:
[image: jackson jars]

Comment: Seems unlikely given this code. Perhaps wrong package used for `@Consumes`?

Comment: Are you expecting XML response (guessing based on the XML annotation on your response class) or JSON response ?

Comment: I'm expecting JSON response and the annotation is working fine when generating JSON with GET method. I have only problem with JSON to JAVA conversion. Any idea ?

Comment: Where are you passing headers ??

Comment: You should look at java logs. Also you can remove JSON.stringify() and check.

Answer (score 1):

Your client is requesting `application/json` in its `Accept` header, but the server does not produce it. Add the `Produces` annotation that declares that the content type is supported.

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response updateTrip(Trip trip) {
```

Beside this, **your server is not responding with JSON**, which is a different problem altogether. You probably want to annotate the method with:

```
@Consumes("text/plain")
```

The most likely fix you need is to make your client send `Accept: */*`, or `Accept: text/plain`

Answer (score -1):

Use Jackson

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Unless you have any specific case, it can convert your XML response to JSON without any additional code.

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants to convert XML to JSON? By the way, that dependency is _insufficient_ to convert XML to JSON...